# If$ f$ is continuous on$ [a,b]$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon $ for all $x\in [a,b]$

how to prove to this by  Heine-Borel theorem
 since $f$ is continuous on closed interval so $f$ is uniformly continuous is this statement we use for this theorem can any hep

Comment: Hint: Suppose the statement is false. Then you get a sequence $(x_n)_n\subset [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)\to 0$. Can you go on? Use Heine-Borel and the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt..you mean $f(x)\to0$

Comment: $f([a,b])$ is compact; thus, closed and bounded. But $f([a,b])\subset (0,\infty)$. The result follows from this.

Comment: thanks every one for help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ certainly attains a minimum on $[a,b]$ say at $c$, then $f(x) \ge f(c)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. But $f(c) > 0$, we can just let this be $\epsilon$, and the claim follows.

Comment: @Deepsea....thank you very much

Comment: its my plez......

Answer (score 1):

By Weierstrass's Theorem, the function attains its minimum on $[a,b].$ Hence there exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that

$$f(x)\leq f(y)\;\forall\; y\in [a,b].$$ Since by hypothesis we have $f(x)>0,$ the result follows

Comment: @Magnusseen...sorry not understand your point

Comment: put $\epsilon=f(x).$

Comment: @Magnusseen..where we used heine-borel theorem

Comment: You used Heine -Borel when you proved Weierstrass theorem

Comment: @Magnusseen..thank you for your time

Comment: Any other proof will, in one way or another, use the same argument that in proving Weierstrass's theorem

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed tu use Weierstrass's Theorem:

let $s:= \inf f([a,b])$. Then there is a sequence $(s_n)$ in $f([a,b])$ with $s_n \to s$. We get a sequence $(t_n)$ in $[a,b]$ such that $s_n=f(t_n)$.

$(t_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence $(t_{n_k})$ with limit $t_0 \in [a,b$]. Then we derive

$s_{n_k}=f(t_{n_k}) \to f(t_0)$. Since $s_{n_k} \to s$, we have

$$s=f(t_0)>0.$$

Comment: I think it is $\inf f([a,b]).$ Also, this is just the proof of Weierstrass's theorem

Comment: @Fred...thank you very much

Comment: @Magnusseen: yes it should read $ \inf$